# problems with cmath overloaded functions C++

Tags: c++, math, overloading

I need to use cmath's abs() function, but Visual Studio says it's overloaded and I can't even use something like this:

```
unsigned a = 5, b = 10, c;
c = abs(a-b);
```

I don't know how to use it properly.

Comment: Also see [Is std::abs(0u) ill-formed?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29750946/1708801)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [versions in `<cmath>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fabs) are for floating point types, so there is no unambiguously best match. The overload for integral types are in [`<cstdlib>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/abs), so one of those will yield a good match. If you are using `abs` on different types, you can use both includes and let overload resolution do its work.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  unsigned int a = 5, b = 10, c;
  c = std::abs(a-b);      
  std::cout << c << "\n"; // Ooops! Probably not what we expected.
}
```

On the other hand, this doesn't yield correct code, since the expression `a-b` does not invoke [integer promotion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast#Integral_promotion), so the result is an `unsigned int`. The real solution is to use signed integral types for differences, as well as the integral type `std::abs` overloads.

Answer (score 2):

As you can see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/abs), there is no cmath function `abs` that takes an unsigned integer. This is because unsigned integers are never negative. Try doing the following instead:

```
int a = 5, b = 10;
int c = abs(a-b);
```

In this case, `c = 5` as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ternary operator:

```
c = (a > b) ? a - b : b - a;
```